# Attaching CollectionViewType to a CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf

This might be simple but I do not know how to go about it. I want to attach a **CollectionViewType** like this: `CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"`  to a **CollectionViewSource**. I am using a typed DataSet and the CollectionViewSource was generated through a Drag and Drop. I am using a DataSet and not Entity Framework.

I have put the following references:

```
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
```

However, I am failing to modify the CollectionViewSorce accordingly.

```
    <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
         Title="MainWindow" 
         Width="500" 
         Height="400" 

         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         >
   <Window.Resources>
         <local:DataSet1 x:Key="DataSet1" />
         <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ExpenseDescriptionsViewSource" Source="{Binding ExpenseDescriptions, Source={StaticResource DataSet1}}" />
   </Window.Resources>

   <Grid >
   </Grid>
   </Window>
```

All the examples I have seen deal with Entity Framework and not with DataSet.

How can I implement CollectionViewType changes in the CollectionViewSource above using DataSset?

Comment: "Attach a CollectionViewType"? Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I mean something like: <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ExpenseDescriptionsViewSource" Source="{Binding ExpenseDescriptions, Source={StaticResource DataSet1}}"  CollectionViewType=”ListCollectionView}" />

Comment: The CollectionViewType depends on the type of the source collection.

Comment: Still no answer?